# Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version

Tags: android, firebase, dart, flutter

I just upgraded to Dart 2 and the latest version of Flutter and now I can't get my app to build. I've looked around on the Internet but still don't understand why this is happening.

The error I get is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

Project build.grade:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^3.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.5
  firebase_database: ^0.4.5
  firebase_core: ^0.2.3

  flutter_blue: ^0.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

I have updated my packages to the latest versions and I'm running the latest version of Dart and Flutter.

I don't really understand what is happening that is causing this error.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020

Comment: @GünterZöchbauerI'd tried all ways but still it's not working!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add the following to the Android Project level build.gradle file's 'subprojects' section (as also mentioned in the [link](http://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020) provided by Günter Zöchbauer in the comment):

```
   subprojects {

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
//[PART TO ADD START]
    project.configurations.all {

        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->

            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
//[PART TO ADD END]
    }
```

Comment: Lost half a day on this !!!!!!!  Was getting ready to punch myself !!!  You saved the day. Thanks to all who got this.

Comment: this helped me as well!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem while I was making a "QR scanner App" in Flutter, I have just changed the "minSdkVersion 21" in **demoapp**->**android**->**app**->**build.gradle**->**minSdkVersion**, it worked perfectly. 
this has happened because some dependency in flutter doesn't support minSdk below 21.

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your project level **build.gradle** file & add the following snippet.

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After adding this, your project level **build.gradle** file will look like this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
       // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Solution provided by **Günter Zöchbauer**. [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14020). It works for me. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
 Open your project **in the android studio** and **wait** for it to **sync** then,

Update **build.gradile** to this
    add **google() in repositories** under build scripts so it looks like this

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
update classpath
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
Update distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip

implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"  // In case your targetting.
```

Comment: Could you please format your answer to make it clear what part is text and what is code?